# Outlook 2016 Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Using Outlook 2016 with WebEx Productivity tool. I created a recurring meeting on my calendar. It went out to all the attendees. They have responded to the meeting request but the meeting does not show up on my calendar. I did not delete the meeting I created it new. It shows up in my Sent folder just like I sent it out.

Any idea how I can recover it or if I can how can I delete it from everybody and resend.

Comment: Can you see the meeting in your webmail interface? If the meeting was somehow deleted, you have to try restoring the meeting to be able to cancel it from everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Have one of the respondents forward it to you, then add yourself
- Login to your [webex profile](https://settings.webex.com/), delete the meeting, and resend it from there

**References**

- [Known Issues and Limitations for Webex Meetings (WBS31)](https://collaborationhelp.cisco.com/article/en-us/nfdzsc8)
- [Cisco Webex SIP Addresses](https://collaborationhelp.cisco.com/article/en-us/n3ltzqcb)